# How to calculate TaskCPUUsage and TaskThreadCount for each process running iPhone or iPad

Tags: objective-c, sysctl

How to calculate TaskCPUUsage and TaskThreadCount for each running process in iPhone or iPad..I want to give the process id and calculate the % cpu for that process.Is it possible? if possible how to do it?
how to get the ProcessID, ProcessName, UserName, %CPU, Threads, Real Mem, Virtual Mem, Architecture, CPU Time and Sudden Term.
programatically I have to calculate those values for running processes in my iPhone.These fields we can see in activity monitor instrument.

Comment: I searched for google code i got this api info from this url http://code.google.com/p/issh-improved/source/browse/AGProcess.m but when i run for cpuusage method it always say that invalid port.

Answer (score -1):

I know from my limited use of I-devices [I am a droid user as I could never afford to pay ~$10 - 15 per app on a rooted phone [for things like SSH access] when I can get them for free in Android.  Not complaining just pointing it out as it is the price you pay for their overly simplified UI approach]

Anyways, I know when looking at fixing an iPhone and jailbreaking it for a client I did see where iPhones are very picky about what user you use in what situation.  I did see one command I cant recall now to get a listing of the users on the device.

I did just find this for you...  It is called iAccounts and states it is for creating accounts with different permissions on a jailbroken iPhone.  It should also have the ability to list all users [including the ton of built-in accounts.  If needed find the code for user account creation if all else fails then have your app go and create the user it needs with just enough permissions to do everything you want it to do [hopefully without giving it FULL root access just ncase your code ever has a problem it helps avoid a catastrophic failure in the system as it only got soo far before ther pemissions on the account it used were exceeded and it was stopped [not saying you would have that type of an error per se but cant account for every scenario and best to error on side of caution as bricking ANY SmartPhone is not fun to recover from]].

http://isource.com/2010/03/05/iaccounts-user-accounts-on-iphone-jailbreak-only/

If you can get a list of built-in accounts there ar different ones to handle different tasks and there is prolly one just for task management and if you can find that one it will prolly get  you what you need.

Oh yeah, dont forget there may be a difference in built-in accounts [whether it be if they exist their default credentials, how to utilize them, etc. between different iOS versions].  I would try and use a couple different iOS versions with your code to see how it reacts in the different versions.